# Anulgar: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ConfigService' before initialization Unit test

Tags: angular, jasmine, config, angular-test

In my angular 15 app, we are loading configuration settings in a configService from back end. I'm using app_initializer to load the settings so that they could be later used in the app. The config service looks like below

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigService { 

 private configEndPoint = '/config';
  public environmentSettings: EnvironmentSettings;
  private http: HttpClient;

  constructor(private readonly httpHandler: HttpBackend, private router: Router) {
    this.http = new HttpClient(httpHandler);
  }

  loadConfig(): Observable<EnvironmentSettings> {
    return this.http
      .get<Config>('./assets/config.json')
      .pipe(
        switchMap(config => {
          return this.http.get<EnvironmentSettings>(config.apiUrl + this.configEndPoint, {
            context: new HttpContext().set(DISABLE_GLOBAL_EXCEPTION_HANDLING, true),
          })
        }),

        tap((settingsFromEndpoint) => {
          this.environmentSettings = settingsFromEndpoint;             
        }),
        shareReplay(1)
      )
  }
```

Provider in the app module looks like

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: configFactory,
      deps: [ConfigService],
      multi: true
    },

export const configFactory = (configService: ConfigService) => {
  return () => configService?.loadConfig();
};
```

Then I inject the config service in the components and services and use config settings, which work great when running the app but when running the unit test I keep getting this error `Error during loading: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ConfigService' before initialization in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js line 7745`

An example of unit test is

```
describe('Service: UserService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    let mockConfigService = jasmine.createSpyObj<ConfigService>(['loadConfig']);
    let mockHttpClient = jasmine.createSpyObj<HttpClient>(['get', 'post', 'put']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),

      ],
      providers: [UserService, SomeOtherService,
        { provide: ConfigService, useValue: mockConfigService },
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should ...', inject([UserService, ConfigService], (service: DocumentsService) => {

    expect(service).toBeTruthy();

  }));
});
```

Any ideas? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try getting rid of this: `inject([UserService, ConfigService]` to see if it makes a difference. You don't need this `inject` syntax, whenever you require a service from the `TestBed`, you can do `TestBed.inject`.

```
it('should...', () => {
  const service = TestBed.inject(UserService);
  expect(service).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: Sorry it does not make a difference. I have the same problem in other services too. Not sure how can I debug this and see where its failling

Comment: Here is a good chapter of a book on how to debug tests: https://testing-angular.com/debugging-tests/.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Just found that its not the unit test that's causing this error. Strangely Injection of configService is causing the error. I have commented out the whole spec file but still getting the error on ng test